# in sql, best syntax for query using subquery more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

from the table

```
create table seeplai.item(
  itm_id  serial  primary key,
  itp_id  int     not null references seeplai.item_type,
  itm_sq  int2    not null default 10,
  ... )
create index item_itp_sq on seeplai.item( itp_id, itm_sq );
```

Using an `item` record as a basis, I wish to find the greatest `itp_sq` having the same  `itp_id` and having `itm_sq` less.  Now using two subqueries, which is syntactically and logically correct, but feels wrong.

```
select  max(itm_sq)
into    v_prev_sq
from    seeplai.item itm
where   itm.itp_id = (select itp_id from seeplai.item where itm_id=p_itm_id)
and     itm.itm_sq < (select itm_sq from seeplai.item where itm_id=p_itm_id);
```

I *know* I have used a better method, but its syntax has dissolved into the cobwebs of my mind

Comment: `itm_tp` is not in your definition?

Comment: `itm_tp` => `itp_id` - fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just *one* greatest `itm_sq` that's smaller than the one in your row:

```
SELECT  i2.itm_sq
FROM    seeplai.item i
JOIN    seeplai.item i2 USING (itp_id)
WHERE   i.itm_id = p_itm_id
AND     i2.itm_sq < i.itm_sq 
ORDER   BY i2.itm_sq DESC
LIMIT   1;
```

To break ties (multiple rows with the same `itm_sq`) you could `ORDER BY` additional columns.

This way you don't have to reuse anything. If you had to, a subquery or [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) would be the tools to use.

---

If you needed the previous `itm_sq` for *every* item sharing the same `itp_id` the window function [**`lag()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (or `lead()` with reversed order) would be instrumental:

```
SELECT  i2.*, lag(i2.itm_sq) OVER (ORDER BY i2.itm_sq) AS previous_itm_sq
FROM    seeplai.item i
JOIN    seeplai.item i2 USING (itp_id)
WHERE   i.itm_id = p_itm_id
ORDER   BY i2.itm_sq DESC;
```

Comment: it's only 8:30 and you're forcing me into my second cup of coffee

Comment: @ccyoung: What ever get's you up to speed. ;)

Comment: ok, this is very cool, as usual.  again my admiration.  and also thanks for not imposing CTE's on me this early.

Comment: as long as `unique( itp_id, itm_sq )` then the first query would work - right?.  (your second solution is the one which I have used many times but today could not remember.)

Comment: My original (now 2nd) query is for a slightly different question (misunderstood at first). It fetches the previous row for *all* items sharing the same `itp_id`. Since you `SELECT INTO` a variable (obviously in plpgsql code), this happens to "work". The first row is used, the rest is discarded. And it may happen to be the correct row, too. But you shouldn't use it, the result is not reliable and not efficient. You want to use my later query (now 1st). I clarified the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table to itself:

```
select max(itm_sq)
into v_prev_sq
from seeplai.item itm
join seeplai.item itm2 on itm.itm_tp = itm2.itm_tp and itm2.itm_id=p_itm_id
join seeplai.item itm3 on itm.itm_sq < itm3.itm_sq and itm3.itm_id=p_itm_id
```

This is a "direct translation" of your query, but I think this simplification will also work:

```
select max(itm_sq)
into v_prev_sq
from seeplai.item itm
join seeplai.item itm2
    on itm.itm_tp = itm2.itm_tp 
    and itm2.itm_id = p_itm_id
    and itm.itm_sq < itm2.itm_sq
```

Comment: your second version makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but perhaps you could use PostgreSQL's [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for common table expressions? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html

Although I would assume that this is easier done using a join actually...

```
select  max(itm_0.itm_sq)
into    v_prev_sq
from    seeplai.item itm_0,
join itm_1
on itm_0.itm_tp = itm_1.itm_tp
and itm_0.itm_sq < itm_1.itm_sq
and itm_0.itm_id = itm_1.p_itm_id
group by itm_1.p_itm_id
```

Possibly using a `DISTINCT ON` if needed

Comment: why are you using the `group by`?

Comment: @ccyoung: you are using a max in your query so I assumed there would be more than 1 row. If not, you can leave out the group by.

Answer (score -1):

Just store the value of the subquery in a variable:

```
declare @retVal varchar(20);
set @retVal = select itm_tp from seeplai.item where itm_id=p_itm_id

select  max(itm_sq)
into    v_prev_sq
from    seeplai.item itm
where   itm.itm_tp = @retVal
and     itm.itm_sq < @retVal;
```

Comment: one could, for sure.  but there's actually a pretty neat way of doing this in single SQL statement that is - unfortunately - completely escaping me now.

Comment: This is not valid Postgres Syntax. Looks like t-SQL?